# Sorting object in JavaScript array numerically

Tags: javascript

```js
var people = [{name: "lily", pts: 30}, {name: "harry", pts: 20}, {name: "jennie", pts: 10}];
points.sort(function(a, b){return b.pts - a.pts});
```

I want to sort everyone in array people by the number of points they have HIGHEST TO LOWEST (descending). is this correct?

Comment: Does it do what you want?

Comment: "*is this correct?*" Well, have you tried it?

Comment: Seems that the code is working. You just want to confirm that is it the correct way to do it. If that's the case then I say it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Javascript to sort an array of numeric arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685843/using-javascript-to-sort-an-array-of-numeric-arrays)

Comment: This is not an array of numeric arrays, he wants to sort an array of objects by a numeric field

Comment: Your array is `people`. But you are sorting `points`. Just change it to: `people.sort(....)`. Other than that, your code should work fine

Comment: This code works by replacing "points" by "people" (or vice versa) since the variable "people" is defined but it is intended to order the inexsitent variable "points".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the "People" array, you just need to sort that array, independent of the `attr` name.

```
var people = [{name: "lily", pts: 22}, {name: "harry", pts: 20},{name: "jennie", pts: 18}];
```

The `array.prototype.sort` function wants to be called in the array.

```
people.sort(function(a,b){
return a.pts - b.pts })
```

Comment: it would be b.pts-apts as it's higest to lowest

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's correct way to sort arrays in JavaScript. You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

P.S. you should call sort function on your people array

```
people.sort(function(a, b){ return a.pts - b.pts; })
```